# Converting CFMutableDataRef to an image

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am building an app which relies heavily on Apples SquareCam example code. In that they take a photo via a custom camera setup with AVFoundation. They save the photo to the camera roll. I would like to store it in the documents directory instead. It seems they are storing the image data in a `CFMutableDataRef` but I'm not sure how to convert this to an image. Any ideas?

Apple's code:

```
    CFMutableDataRef destinationData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(destinationData,
                                                                     CFSTR("public.jpeg"),
                                                                     1,
                                                                     NULL);
BOOL success = (destination != NULL);
require(success, bail);

const float JPEGCompQuality = 0.85f; 
CFMutableDictionaryRef optionsDict = NULL;
CFNumberRef qualityNum = NULL;

qualityNum = CFNumberCreate(0, kCFNumberFloatType, &JPEGCompQuality);
if ( qualityNum ) {
    optionsDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(0, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    if ( optionsDict )
        CFDictionarySetValue(optionsDict, kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality, qualityNum);
    CFRelease( qualityNum );
}

CGImageDestinationAddImage( destination, cgImage, optionsDict );
success = CGImageDestinationFinalize( destination );

if ( optionsDict )
    CFRelease(optionsDict);

require(success, bail);

CFRetain(destinationData);
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];
[library writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:(id)destinationData metadata:metadata completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
    if (destinationData)
        CFRelease(destinationData);
}];

[library release];
```

Answer (score 1):

`CFMutableDataRef` is toll-free bridged to `NSMutableData`, so you can probably cast the `CFMutableDataRef` to `NSMutableData` or `NSData` (or assign it to a variable of that type) and call one of the `writeToFile:` or `writeToURL:` methods on it to store it to the filesystem and see if that yields an image file.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. I get a warning 'instance method not found'.

Comment: I should have been more specific about casting it or storing it in a variable with type `NSData` or `NSMutableData`—I've edited my answer to indicate that.  If you cast it or store it in a variable with that type, do you still get the instance method not found error?

Comment: Should have thought of that, I'm not getting the warning anymore so hopefully it will work. I'll come back and select your answer once I've tested it. Thanks!